# How to make a Java Object Synchronized? Which approch is better and why?

Tags: java, synchronization

I am getting confused which one should I use to make a synchronized singleton class object. I know below 2 ways of achieving it.

```
static volatile PaymentSettings paymentSettings = null;

public static PaymentSettings getInstance() {
    if (paymentSettings == null) {
        synchronized (PaymentSettings.class) {
            if (paymentSettings == null)
                paymentSettings = new PaymentSettings();
        }
    }
    return paymentSettings;
}
```

And

```
 private static class PaymentSettingsInstanceHolder {
    private static PaymentSettings instance = new PaymentSettings();
}

public static PaymentSettings getInstance() {
    return PaymentSettingsInstanceHolder.instance;
}
```

Please suggest which approach should I use and why?

Comment: This isn't making an object synchronised. I'm not sure I even know what that means. This creates a lazily initialised singleton! And the second method is far better.

Comment: Syncronization via `synchronized (PaymentSettings.class)` may lead to deadlocks (rarely, but possible) since the lock is available from the outside (that is, if a caller is syncronizing on that lock too). If you like to do synchrinized lazy init, you may just use LazyInitializer from Apache commons. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html - Apart from that: The two approach differ in the time of construction (lazy vs. non-lazy) and not how they do synchronization - which one is better depends on may other aspects.

Comment: Better always depends on the goals you want to achieve. You don't state those in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: The difference is the initialization moment. On the first call to `getInstance()` in the first version and the class loading in the second version, which is less predictable.

Comment: @ChristianFries this is **a lie**. Both approaches **are lazy**.

Comment: @ChristianFries You can't get a deadlock unless there are two or more locks acquired in different orders. What you are describing is merely a *block.*

Comment: @BoristheSpider bit harsh, being incorrect != being a liar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two mechanisms are common attempts at achieving a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

The first is called [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and is generally considered broken, although your technique of locking against the class may be an acceptable work-around.

Your second is a tidy solution but may create the object when not needed.

The nowadays considered best solution is using an `enum`. This ensure that the object is only created when needed and not before. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/823393) for an excellent discourse on why this is good.

```
final class Singleton {

    private Singleton() {
        // Make sure only I can create one.
    }

    private enum Single {

        INSTANCE;
        // The only instance - ever.
        final Singleton s = new Singleton();

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        // Will force the construction here only.
        return Single.INSTANCE.s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that most of this is so it matches OP's original signature as `public enum PaymentSettings { INSTANCE; }` is all they really need. Or are they other reasons for this way?

Comment: @weston - Yes there's more. The `enum` ensures construction at the last minute and only once. It also provides serialization out of the box. Also the presence of `private Singleton ...` guarantees the contract of **there can be only one**. Also, you should not expose the `enum` itself, you should let the `enum` instanciate the singleton.

Comment: I know why enum, I was asking what has your longer way, got over the shorter way I posted (and that you linked to). It hides the enum, but why is that better? Also you should have the class `final` if you do do it your way.

Comment: Both the solutions proposed by the OP are **lazy**. The DCL is fine because of `volatile`. Your proposed solution is **eager**.  Which is more appropriate solely depends on use case.

Comment: It hasn't been 'considered broken' since they tightened the memory model in Java 1.5, quite a few years ago now.

Comment: @weston - Your method 2 will create the singleton when *any* access to your `PaymentSettingsInstanceHolder` - e.g. a static method etc. Mine would **only** create the instance when `getInstance` is called and is therefore as late as possible.

Comment: Fair enough, but easier to keep the static methods elsewhere I would think.